# Povray "hangs" on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, freeze

I've installed PovRay 3.7 on a Ubuntu 14.04 server using the default "povray" package to experiment with it as a tool to dynamically generate graphics for a website.

Whichever script I try, it keeps "hanging". I use quotes because I don't know if this is actually hanging; it just doesn't seem to finish without a little user intervention.

I start a script using `povray +Ifilename.pov`, it then shows it's progress upto an `Antialiasing......Off` statement and does nothing more. In the directory there is an extra `filename-state` file.

However, if I use `ctrl+z` then `fg`, it immediately continues and finishes (usually claiming a ~1 sec. trace time) and creates a correctly rendered `filename.png` file.

However, this only happens on consecutive runs of povray. The first run after a reboot of the server goes perfect, only every run after the first (until next server reboot) shows this behaviour.

I've tried several example scripts from the manual and from outside sources; they all act the same way.

Does anybody know what is happening and what I can do to fix it?

`strace povray -i{scriptname}` produces an endless list of these:

```
futex(0x19c7988, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
futex(0x19c79b4, FUTEX_WAIT_BITSET_PRIVATE|FUTEX_CLOCK_REALTIME, 729, {1415657359, 593721000}, ffffffff) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
futex(0x19c7988, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
futex(0x19c79b4, FUTEX_WAIT_BITSET_PRIVATE|FUTEX_CLOCK_REALTIME, 731, {1415657359, 794168000}, ffffffff) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
futex(0x19c7988, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
futex(0x19c79b4, FUTEX_WAIT_BITSET_PRIVATE|FUTEX_CLOCK_REALTIME, 733, {1415657359, 994601000}, ffffffff
```

Comment: Addendum; I've tried the `povray` package on an Ubuntu 12.04 server as well, and it works just fine. Perhaps something bad with the CentOS package or configuration?

Comment: Could you try `strace <povray command>` from the command line and append the last few lines to your question? The program `strace` is used to [show the interactions between povray and the OS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/174942/how-should-strace-be-used). Maybe (just maybe!) it gives us some clue to what Povray is waiting/hanging on.

Comment: @agtoever: I'm just seeing what seems like an endless loop of these: `futex(0x19c7988, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
futex(0x19c79b4, FUTEX_WAIT_BITSET_PRIVATE|FUTEX_CLOCK_REALTIME, 733, {1415657359, 994601000}, ffffffff`. The `733` number keeps increasing. Upto 2200 now and still going. The numbers `1415657359, 994601000` increase as well; 1st seems a unix timestamp, 2nd has no easily discernable pattern.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer**
I'm not sure it this answer qualifies as an answer, but I guess a respectful "I can't reproduce your problem" is also some sort of an answer. Also, I wanted to include some info, which would not fit in a comment.

**I can't reproduce the problem**
I can't reproduce the problem using Ubuntu on a virtual box. I used Ubutu 14.04 LTS x86_64 all updates (per 13 nov 2014) applied, basic server install with kernel 3.13.0-39-generic and POVRAY from the Ubuntu package manager. If you have an other version than that, please let me know (in a comment), and I'll give it another try.

The output of my `Povray --version` is:

```
POV-Ray 3.7.0.unofficial

This is an unofficial version compiled by:
 Felix Geyer <debfx@ubuntu.com> for Debian <www.debian.org>
 The POV-Ray Team is not responsible for supporting this version.

Copyright 1991-2013 Persistence of Vision Raytracer Pty. Ltd.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Built-in features:
  I/O restrictions:          enabled
  X Window display:          enabled (using SDL)
  Supported image formats:   gif tga iff ppm pgm hdr png jpeg tiff openexr
  Unsupported image formats: -

Compilation settings:
  Build architecture:  x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
  Built/Optimized for: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
  Compiler vendor:     gnu
  Compiler version:    g++ 4.8
  Compiler flags:      -pipe -Wno-multichar -Wno-write-strings -fno-enforce-eh-specs -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -O3 -pthread
```

I tried to raytrace several .pov example files, which all worked flawlessly. For example this is my output (cleaned it up a bit) for bezier.pov:

```
Persistence of Vision(tm) Ray Tracer Version 3.7.0.unofficial (g++ 4.8 @ x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
This is an unofficial version compiled by: Felix Geyer <debfx@ubuntu.com> for Debian <www.debian.org>
The POV-Ray Team is not responsible for supporting this version.
POV-Ray is based on DKBTrace 2.12 by David K. Buck & Aaron A. Collins
Copyright 1991-2013 Persistence of Vision Raytracer Pty. Ltd.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
<<...cut some credits here...>>
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Parser Options
  Input file: /usr/share/doc/povray/examples/objects/bezier.pov
Remove bounds........On 
Split unions.........Off
Library paths:
    /usr/share/povray-3.7
    /usr/share/povray-3.7/ini
    /usr/share/povray-3.7/include
Clock value:    0.000  (Animation off)
Image Output Options
Image resolution.....800 by 600 (rows 1 to 600, columns 1 to 800).
Output file........../usr/share/doc/povray/examples/objects/bezier.png, 24 bpp PNG
Dithering............Off
Graphic display......On  (gamma: sRGB)
Mosaic preview.......Off
Continued trace......Off
Information Output Options
All Streams to console..........On 
Debug Stream to console.........On 
Fatal Stream to console.........On 
Render Stream to console........On 
Statistics Stream to console....On 
Warning Stream to console.......On 

==== [Parsing...] ==========================================================
Parser Statistics
Finite Objects:            1
Infinite Objects:          1
Light Sources:             1
Total:                     3

Parser Time
  Parse Time:       0 hours  0 minutes  0 seconds (0.011 seconds)
  using 1 thread(s) with 0.010 CPU-seconds total
  Bounding Time:    0 hours  0 minutes  0 seconds (0.000 seconds)
  using 1 thread(s) with 0.000 CPU-seconds total
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Render Options 
  Quality:  9
  Bounding boxes.......On   
  Bounding threshold: 3
  Antialiasing.........Off
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Render Statistics
Image Resolution 800 x 600
Pixels:           480000   
Samples:               0   
Smpls/Pxl: 0.00
Rays:             480000   
Saved:                 0   
Max Level: 1/5

Ray->Shape Intersection          Tests       Succeeded  Percentage
 Bicubic Patch                   725967          122319     16.85
 Plane                           959954          480000     50.00
 Bounding Box                    959954          627633     65.38
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Shadow Ray Tests:            479996   
Succeeded:                    46
Shadow Cache Hits:               42
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Render Time:
Photon Time:      No photons
Radiosity Time:   No radiosity
Trace Time:       0 hours  0 minutes  2 seconds (2.185 seconds)
using 4 thread(s) with 1.683 CPU-seconds total
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
POV-Ray finished
```

**The cause of the problem and a (possible) "solution"**
Based on the input from the `strace`, I'd say your povray is also compiled using the `-pthread` flag, and somehow one child process terminates without releasing the futex and thus locking the main povray thread. Your strance gave the output of the main povray thread, but it did not include strace info of the chiled processes. If you *really* want to know what's going on, you can try `ps -efL | grep povray` (more info in [this blog](http://meenakshi02.wordpress.com/2011/02/02/strace-hanging-at-futex/)), which *might* give some more insight  on what's locking your povray.

If you *really* want to solve this, I suggest you first try to get the -dev version of povray and compile it yourself on your machine and see if that makes a difference. Alternatively, you can grab [the sources files from Povray](http://www.povray.org/download/linux.php) and give that a try.

Finally, you might want to leave a [bug report at Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs), so they can take a look at it.